# parameters in REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, regexp-substr

I wanted to extract all the "name" values from this:

```
{"id":"1","name":"simpleword","type":"test"},{"id":"123","name":"f23ÜÜ","type":"prod"}
```

I was presented with the following solution;

```
regexp_substr_all(s, 'name":"([^"]*)"', 1, 1, '', 1)
```

and now I am trying to understand the regex. I understand that the

```
'name":"([^"]*)"'
```

part extracts the whole part:

```
"name":"simpleword",
"name":"f23ÜÜ"
```

but how is the `1, 1, '', 1` working to extract the values of the name keys only?

Comment: See [`REGEXP_SUBSTR_ALL` reference](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr_all.html#regexp-substr-all). These are `<position> [ , <occurrence> [ , <regex_parameters> [ , <group_num> ] ` args.

Comment: Yes, I have already seen the names, but how are they helping in extract the name values? How is the occurence and position working here? @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how is the 1, 1, '', 1 working to extract the values of the name keys
> only?

They are all explained here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr_all.html#arguments

> Yes, I have already seen the names, but how are they helping in
> extract the name values?

In your case, position and occurrence are default values, so they are just entered to be able to enter the rest of the parameters. I don't think regex_parameters is important but the group number (last 1) is required otherwise the regexp will not care about grouping (), and will return the whole matching string:

Comment: makes sense. about ```"([^"]*)"``` this part, i understand that we group everything between the ```"  "``` but why is there another ```"``` inside the square brackets?

Comment: It says any character but not ". So it takes the words between " characters.